# How Can I combine these meshes without it smoothing out?

Tags: mesh, objects, import

[image]I'm still new to blender so I'm following tutorials and things to make this character. At some point while working on attaching the head to the body I accidently deleted a piece of her knee, so I imported in an old model that still had the knee. But when I bring it in it has these blue lines on all the edges, and when I join the two meshes the new knee I brought in smoothes out like it has a subdivision surface modifier on it (even though I've never put one on the body yet). I know I could rebuild it I just want to troubleshoot why this wouldn't work.

Comment: the blue edges look like Mark Sharp. In Edit mode/Edge Select, try to select all and right click > Clear Sharp? Also in object mode right click and Shade Smooth or Flat depending on what you want

Comment: Thank you!! shade flat brought it back to normal! I had a feeling it would be a stupidly simple fix lol thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The blue edges look like *Mark Sharp*. In *Edit* mode/*Edge Select*, try to select all and right click > *Clear Sharp*. Also in *Object* mode right click and *Shade Smooth* or *Flat* depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just at a glance, I can tell you have flipped/mismatched face orientation. Select all those faces, go to Mesh > Normals > Flip. I'm not sure about the smoothing, but that should help

Comment: hmmm, I did check that and it all came up blue. for safety though I did as you suggested just in case (flipped them to red and back to blue).